# Equality comparator for two qubits each

Tags: grovers-algorithm, oracles

I'm trying to implement Grover's algorithm. For the oracle I have three nodes which are represented by two qubits for each node. How can I check if the states of two nodes are not equal?

[image]

Comment: Hi!  Where did you get this from?  Is it a lecture series? A textbook?  Do you know what the [SWAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_test) test does?

Comment: Got it from here (slide 10): https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/37767943.pdf

Comment: Slide 10 appears to illustrate a possible oracle for coloring; I think you need to consider how to convert all of slide 10 into a *reversible* circuit, using, for example, $\mathsf{CCNOT}$ gates.  The $\mathsf{NEQ}$ steps are easy and reversible, the output of the $\mathsf{AND}$ gate is not.  Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I've already did that (converting everything into a reversible circuit) to a certain degree. What's missing or what I'm currently interested in is really the **NEQ** steps.